# How can I use a Guice module within a Spring (specifically Spring Boot) context?

Tags: java, spring-boot, guice

I have many "legacy" JAVA jars that were written with Guice dependency injection. I would like to use them in a new Spring Boot application but I appear to be having some issues getting this to work. I noticed that there is a project that indicates it is possible to use a Spring Context in a Guice module (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice), but I would like to do the reverse of that.

Should I just drop the attempt and keep using Guice? Spring boot provides some nice features that I would like to use.

---

In theory this post answers my question, but I am hoping that something has changed or gotten easier in the last 4 years.

[Integrate Guice component into Spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826308/integrate-guice-component-into-spring-application)

A wrapper seems feasible, but could lead to other consequences.

Comment: the question you linkes has answers from just 2 years ago, the spring-guice project seems active.