# Integrating Spring into an existing Guice project and take beans from Guice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, guice

I am trying to develop a Server-Side application, that handles management of stuff (i don't want to go into detail).

The Application is separated into several modules. Those include, but are not limited to:

- network communictaion
- data-access
- data-query
- integrated UI

All of said modules are decoupled and the top most module is the the IntegratedWebUI (integrated UI). All modules only expose interfaces and those interfaces are wired together using Guice IOC.

For the integrated UI, i want to use Spring. Spring brings a IOC container with it, i know, but i dont want the other modules to know about Spring, to make it more interchangable (like changing it, without touching the other modules).

***My concrete question***: What is the most elegant way, to hook Spring to Guice in the manner that Spring tries to take beans from the Guice injector?

---

I already know about [spring-guice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice) which somehow resembles something like this. However, i want to decouple the IntegratedWebUI completely and never change the configuration *inside* of the WebUI modules (hence the Guice injector), i.e. changing the behaviour by changing the guice module configuration.

In the examples for spring-guice, the provided hooks only create concrete Objects, but i want to be able to tell Spring: "try to create any object from Guice" (like using a generic, which appears to not be feasible). Is something like this at all possible?

Both Spring and Guice appear to use the [JSR330](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826308/integrate-guice-component-into-spring-application). Would it be possible to write some Spring Controller, that are instantiated through Spring and use javax.inject.@Inject to get dependencies from other modules which are wired using Guice?

Comment: did you get this to work?

Comment: @alihaider Yes and no. I had to create a class, which is resolved by Guice and provides Spring beans. Ugly but it works. However, this question is closed because it is "too broad". Sorry..

Comment: can you please post the relevant code as answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962016/trying-to-access-spring-bean-from-guice-module