# trying to access spring bean from guice module

Tags: java, spring, guice

I am using guice 4.2.2 in my Java application and need to utilize Spring beans (as part of a library I need to incorporate into my application).  I have tried using SpringIntegration within guice and I am able to print the names of the beans loaded.  However, when I try to access an object using injector.getInstance, the object I get is null.

Any thoughts on how I can go about troubleshooting this further?  I can use Spring-projects's spring-guice integration if needed.

**guice module**

```
public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {

 @override
 protected void configure() {


   final ClassPathXmlContext ctx = getApplicationcontext();

   SpringIntegration.bindall(binder(), ctx.getBeanFactory());
   bind(ApplicationContext.class.toInstance(ctx));

}


 private Applicationcontext getApplicationcontext() {
   final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
   final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
   ctx.setClassLoader(classLoader);
   ctx.setConfiguration("test-context.xml");
   ctx.refresh();
   return ctx;
} 

}
```

In a class (instead of using annotation), I am trying to get an instance as follows:

```
  final TestClient client = injector.getInstance(TestClient.class);
```

I have tried using a class that will gt injected with the Spring bean using guice but when I access that bean, it appears to be null.  Any thoughts?

Comment: can you post here the code, how did you injected?

Comment: @GvSharma just added code snippet.  thanks

Comment: how do you inject here? can you post that code?

Comment: I was trying to get an instance using getInstance to test if this integration will work (not injecting)

Comment: TestClient() . => you have injected this bean using annotations right? what is that annotation?

Comment: I am getting an instance of TestClient using the injector.getInstance call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199536/discussion-between-gvsharma-and-ali-haider).

Comment: thank you for the help offered